# Scala Parser Token Delimiter Problem

Tags: scala, parsing, bnf, ebnf, parser-combinators

I'm trying to define a grammar for the commands below.

```
object ParserWorkshop {
    def main(args: Array[String]) = {
        ChoiceParser("todo link todo to database")
        ChoiceParser("todo link todo to database deadline: next tuesday context: app.model")
    }
}
```

The second command should be tokenized as:

```
action = todo
message = link todo to database
properties = [deadline: next tuesday, context: app.model]
```

When I run this input on the grammar defined below, I receive the following error message:

```
[1.27] parsed: Command(todo,link todo to database,List())
[1.36] failure: string matching regex `\z' expected but `:' found

todo link todo to database deadline: next tuesday context: app.model
                                   ^
```

As far as I can see it fails because the pattern for matching the words of the message is nearly identical to the pattern for the key of the property key:value pair, so the parser cannot tell where the message ends and the property starts. I can solve this by insisting that start token be used for each property like so:

```
todo link todo to database :deadline: next tuesday :context: app.model
```

But i would prefer to keep the command as close natural language as possible.
I have two questions:

What does the error message actually mean?
And how would I modify the existing grammar to work for the given input strings?

```
import scala.util.parsing.combinator._

case class Command(action: String, message: String, properties: List[Property])
case class Property(name: String, value: String)

object ChoiceParser extends JavaTokenParsers {
    def apply(input: String) = println(parseAll(command, input))

    def command = action~message~properties ^^ {case a~m~p => new Command(a, m, p)}

    def action = ident

    def message = """[\w\d\s\.]+""".r

    def properties = rep(property)

    def property = propertyName~":"~propertyValue ^^ {
        case n~":"~v => new Property(n, v)
    }

    def propertyName: Parser[String] = ident

    def propertyValue: Parser[String] = """[\w\d\s\.]+""".r
}
```

Comment: I think you should change your syntax to something like this:

todo "link todo to database" :deadline: "next tuesday" :context: "app.model"

Comment: This is a solution I want to avoid, as I want to keep the Todo grammar as close to a natural language as possible.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It is really simple. When you use `~`, you have to understand that there's no backtracking on individual parsers which have completed succesfully.

So, for instance, `message` got everything up to before the colon, as all of that is an acceptable pattern. Next, `properties` is a `rep` of `property`, which requires `propertyName`, but it only finds the colon (the first char not gobbled by `message`). So `propertyName` fails, and `property` fails. Now, `properties`, as mentioned, is a `rep`, so it finishes succesfully with 0 repetitions, which then makes `command` finish succesfully.

So, back to `parseAll`. The `command` parser returned succesfully, having consumed everything before the colon. It then asks the question: are we at the end of the input (`\z`)? No, because there is a colon right next. So, it expected end-of-input, but got a colon.

You'll have to change the regex so it won't consume the last identifier before a colon. For example:

```
def message = """[\w\d\s\.]+(?![:\w])""".r
```

By the way, when you use `def` you force the expression to be reevaluated. In other words, each of these defs create a parser every time each one is called. The regular expressions are instantiated every time the parsers they belong to are processed. If you change everything to `val`, you'll get much better performance.

Remember, these things *define* the parser, they do not *run* it. It is `parseAll` which runs a parser.